# hibernate 4 - how to substitute JDBCContext.registerSynchronizationIfPossible()

Tags: java, hibernate

As we already know `JdbcContext` class is gone from hibernate 4. Now, I am wondering what is the mechanism to substitute the logic of registerSynchronizationIfPossible() method of JdbcContext, taking into account that a lot of other related interfaces (`TransactionFactory` etc) have also changed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.TransactionCoordinator#pulse`.  That is the method directly responsible for the same things that `JdbcContext#registerSynchronizationIfPossible` used to do